# ¿Como actualizar los duplicate entry con un trigger?

Tags: mysql

Quiero actualizar los registros duplicados con un trigger usando ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, pero no logro hacerlo, siempre obtengo el error 1442
Esta es mi tabla, y este es el código:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba(
    PRUEBA_ID NUMERIC(15) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAIT PK_prueba PRIMARY KEY (PRUEBA_ID),
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPCION TEXT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);  

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON  prueba 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        INSERT INTO prueba(PRUEBA_ID,NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION)
VALUES(new.PRUEBA_ID,new.NOMBRE,new.DESCRIPCION)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
NOMBRE=new.NOMBRE,
DESCRIPCION=new.DESCRIPCION;
    END; //
```

el error que obtengo es el siguiente:  Row import failed with error: ("Can't update table 'prueba' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.", 1442)

LO QUE CAUSA EL DUPLICADO ES LA LLAVE PRIMARIA PRUEBA_ID

Comment: Pon el mensaje de error completo. Además, si lo que causa el duplicado es la columna nombre no tiene sentido querer asignarle `new.NOMBRE`, conviene que aclares eso en tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es  la causa del duplicado?

Comment: Lo que causa el duplicado es la llave primaria PRUEBA_ID, el mensaje de error que obtengo es el siguiente : Row import failed with error: ("Can't update table 'prueba' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.", 1442), lo que quiero hacer es que si se repite este ID, actualice los campos nombre y descripcion con los nuevos valores que sean insertados, la insercion se hace desde un csv usando LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Entiendo. Me pregunto, ¿por qué quieres usar un TRIGGER aquí cuando bastaría escribir la consulta **desde fuera** de este modo: `INSERT INTO prueba(PRUEBA_ID,NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION)
VALUES(...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
NOMBRE=...,
DESCRIPCION=...` como es lógico, cambiarías los `...` por los diferentes valores que quieres insertar. Un TRIGGER no es necesario para esto. Y si lo que quieres es normalizar, tampoco es un TRIGGER lo adecuado para esta normalización. En este caso el código está fallando porque los TRIGGER recursivos no existen en MySQL (un TRIGGER no puede modificarse a sí mismo).

Comment: *un TRIGGER no puede modificarse a sí mismo* ... o dicho de un modo más correcto, un TRIGGER no puede modificar a la misma tabla que lo dispara, esto no es posible en MySQL. Eso es lo que te está queriendo decir con *Can't update table 'prueba' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger*. No puede actualizar la tabla `prueba` porque es ella la que dispara.

Comment: ¿Actualizar el ID? Eso es nuevo en tu pregunta. En ninguna parte aparece que quieras actualizar el ID ¿? Si es eso lo que quieres tendrás que explicar más cosas, por ejemplo, ¿qué política de actualización tienes definida cuado haya un ID duplicado? (algo como tomar el último y sumarle uno) y más preguntas surgirían, ¿por qué esa columna es NUMERIC y no auto-incremental? ¿qué justifica que en tu aplicación se produzcan IDs duplicados sin control? ¿no deberías evitar eso de algún modo, por ejemplo verificando antes de insertar?

Comment: La razon por la cual existen duplicados es porque es un reporte que se va actualizando dia con dia, por ejemplo 

| ID               | Fecha             |   Descripcion |
  CH-5676       No definida    Sin descripcion

Al siguiente dia puede aparecer de la siguiente forma

| ID               | Fecha                 |   Descripcion |
  CH-5676       04 octubre 2021    Corte de fibra


Y el hecho de que no sea auto-incremental es porque el numero de ticket varia dependiendo el cliente, esta ultima parte no requiere explicacion puesto que la intencion de la pregunta es una consulta

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para agregar a la pregunta cualquier cosa que ayude a entender el contexto. Intuyo que más que nada lo que ocurre aquí es un error de diseño en tu base de datos. Conviene que expliques cómo se generan los IDs, por qué has decidido que esa columna sea NUMERIC y no de otro tipo y cómo piensas controlar los duplicados. Generalmente esto se controla a otro nivel, no tirándoselo a la base de datos para que ella resuelva errores de diseño. Tú deberías controlar en el programa que no sea posible agregar datos duplicados.